# Vue.js 2 - Computed property in v-for list repeater

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to add some computed columns to a table (see last three columns). I have a feeling it has to do with the computed property not referencing the record correctly. I am sure missing something simple! Any ideas? Thank you!

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0770ct39/2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vue.js Tutorial | More Computed Properties</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Phase</th>
                        <th>Labour Budget</th>
                        <th>Labour Hours</th>
                        <th>Labour Cost Rate</th>
                        <th>Labour Cost</th>
                        <th>Overhead Cost</th>
                        <th>Net</th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="record in records">
                        <td>{{record.phase}}</td>
                        <td>{{record.labourBudget}}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" v-model="record.labourHours"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" v-model="record.labourCostRate"></td>
                        <td>{{record.labourCost}}</td>
                        <td>{{record.overheadCost}}</td>
                        <td>{{record.net}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        records: [
            {phase:"Phase1", labourBudget: 100, labourHours: 4, labourCostRate: 45},
            {phase:"Phase2", labourBudget: 100, labourHours: 2, labourCostRate: 42}
        ]
      },
      computed: {
        labourCost: function(){
            return this.record.labourHours * this.record.labourCostRate;
        },
        overheadCost: function(){
            return this.record.labourCost * 1.36;
        },
        net: function(){
            return this.record.netRevenue-this.record.labourCost-this.record.overheadCost;
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make each row its own component and pass the `record` to that in order for this to work. If you don't want to make a component you can use `methods` instead.

You could essentially do:

```
methods: {
  laborCost: function(record) {
    return record.labourHours * record.labourCostRate
  },
  ...
}
```

Then use it like

```
{{ laborCost(record) }}
```

If you wanted to go the component route (which I think you should) you'd do something like this:

```
<record v-for="record in records" :record="record"></record>
```

Then you can copy and paste those computed properties into that component and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I got it working with methods as you suggested! https://jsfiddle.net/k72qkbtp/
Is it right to assume this is not the best approach because it does not cache the data like computed properties which is why you recommend the component approach (otherwise it can get slow if using many rows and columns)? 

I tried revising it to the component approach and got this far - what am i missing?
https://jsfiddle.net/h1ujpft0/

Comment: I think I got it using components Bill! https://jsfiddle.net/sb0b36ju/
For some reason it throws the template above the table - any ideas how to fix that? Also, is this the best way to do it compared to methods in terms of performance?

Comment: You just replied as I was typing my initial reply. This looks right. To get the table to render right you need to do `<tr is="data-row" v-for="record in records" :record="record"></tr>` though.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Comment: Thanks Bill! I'm so close! https://jsfiddle.net/jn9Lf1dy/
Getting this error:
[Vue warn]: Component template should contain exactly one root element:

<td>{{record.phase}}</td>
    <td>{{record.labourBudget}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model="record.labourHours"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model="record.labourCostRate"></td>
    <td>{{labourCost}}</td>
    <td>{{overheadCost}}</td>
    <td>{{net}}</td>

Comment: You need to include the `<tr>` in your template too.

Comment: AMAZING!! Thank you so much you Bill!! :)

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: To anyone else reading this - here is the working fiddle with components (thanks to Bill)! https://jsfiddle.net/jn9Lf1dy/1/

Comment: Bill, sorry to bother you! Everything works but noticed in console still getting the following error - any advice how to correct it?

[Vue warn]: Component template should contain exactly one root element:

<tr>
        <td>{{record.phase}}</td>
        <td>{{record.labourBudget}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="record.labourHours"></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="record.labourCostRate"></td>
        <td>{{labourCost}}</td>
        <td>{{overheadCost}}</td>
        <td>{{net}}</td>
    <tr>

Answer (score 2):

The reason your computed property functions aren't working is because the `this` keyword refers to your Vue instance. For example.. if you changed your computed functions like this...

```
computed: {
  labourCost: function() {
    return app.record.labourHours * app.record.labourCostRate;
  }
}
```

...it would be functionally equivalent to what you have now because the `app` variable refers to your Vue instance.

So, in your current state, when Vue processes your computed properties it says "hey! there's no data property named record! I mean, I see one called `records`, but none called `record`".

I would recommend returning a computed array of all the records like so.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    records: [
        {phase:"Phase1", labourBudget: 100, labourHours: 4, labourCostRate: 45},
        {phase:"Phase2", labourBudget: 100, labourHours: 2, labourCostRate: 42}
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    rows: function() {
      return this.records.map(function(record) {
        return Object.assign({}, record, {
          labourCost : record.labourHours * record.labourCostRate,
          overheadCost : record.labourCost * 1.36,
          net : record.netRevenue-record.labourCost-record.overheadCost
        });
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Then change the loop in your html to

```
<tr v-for="record in rows">
```

NOTE: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is an ES2015 thing. But you can use this [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).  Or you can use an alternative object-merge function like lodash's [_.assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#assign) or [jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

Comment: Thanks Jesse! It worked for the first column on load, but not for the other two and does not seem to update when changing the values. I tried putting in the Object.assign polyfill - perhaps I didn't use it correctly? 
https://jsfiddle.net/wt178zbz/